# Distributing a .NET app with Excel interaction

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, deployment, office-interop

I've been coding with VB2005 for some time and in the process of converting to VB2010. At the time I just cant convert this project so I'm stuck on VB2005. The project interacts with Excel 2010. On my machine and those in my group it works great. Now I have installed it on a different group's machine and am getting an error

- *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
  system cannot find the file specified. File name:
  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c*

The target machine has .NET2 and office 2010 installed. I have also installed the Office2010PIAs. I rebooted and yet I still get this error. I'm not sure I understand what needs to be on the target machine for this to work. Is it that in my References for the project the Excel 14.0 and Office 14.0 libraries are set to CopyLocal=False? I always thought that if the PIAs are installed to the target machine then I don't need local copies. Any suggestions? What is the proper way to deploy this type of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CopyLocal could be the problem, trying setting libraries to copy to output directory.

Comment: I did that and it worked. Although I did make a mistake. The end user has Office 2007 installed so maybe I just installed the wrong PIAs. Ill test again tomorrow.